# SQL Server - Combine rows into one field for each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

On SQL Server 2012, when I run:

```
SELECT Customer, Fruit
FROM Customers_DB
```

I get the following as outputs:

```
| Customer      | Fruit     |
| A0001         | Apple     |
| A0001         | Pear      |
| A0002         | Banana    |
| A0003         | Pear      |
| A0004         | Grape     |
| A0004         | Apricot   |
```

How would I achieve the following outputs, dynamically?

```
| Customer      | Fruit           |
| A0001         | Apple + Pear    |
| A0002         | Banana          |
| A0003         | Pear            |
| A0004         | Apricot + Grape |
```

I note that the Fruit are concatenated (maybe `Coalesce`'d in alphabetical order).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: This has been asked and answered thousands of times.

Comment: @SeanLange Then why have you only posted one solitary question and answer?

Comment: Because I didn't feel I needed to do your research. I provided you an excellent example of how to do this. I figured instead of marking this as a duplicate I would point you to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stuff as below:

```
Select Customer, 
    stuff((select ' + '+Fruit from #customer_db c where c.customer = c1.customer order by Fruit for xml path('')),1,3,'') as Fruit
from #customer_db c1
group by customer
```

Output as below:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| Customer |      Fruit      |
+----------+-----------------+
| A0001    | Apple + Pear    |
| A0002    | Banana          |
| A0003    | Pear            |
| A0004    | Apricot + Grape |
+----------+-----------------+
```

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or SQL Azure then you can use String_agg